# taking data from files which are in folder

Tags: python, directory

How do I get the data from multiple txt files that placed in a specific folder. I started with this could not fix. It gives an error like 'No such file or directory: '.idea' (??)
(Let's say I have an A folder and in that, there are x.txt, y.txt, z.txt and so on. I am trying to get and print the information from all the files x,y,z)

```
def find_get(folder):
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        f = open(file, 'r')
        for data in open(file, 'r'):
            print data

find_get('filex')
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to write all the information into 1 text file?

Comment: what are you trying to do? that should get file data from a folder ... and print it

Comment: Let's say I have an A folder and in that, there are x.txt, y.txt, z.txt and so on. I am trying to get and print the information from all the files x,y,z...

Comment: The reason you're getting this error is that `os.listdir` just returns filenames, not pathnames. Unless `folder` happens to be your current working directory, you need to `join` its path to each filename. That will fix your exception. Whether the rest of your code does what you want seems hard to guess.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to print each line:

```
import glob
import os

def find_get(path):
    for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"*.txt")):
        with open(os.path.join(path, f)) as data:
            for line in data:
                print(line)
```

[glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) will find only your `.txt` files in the specified path.

Your error comes from not joining the path to the filename, unless the file was in the same directory you were running the code from python would not be able to find the file without the full path. Another issue is you seem to have a directory `.idea` which would also give you an error when trying to open it as a file. This also presumes you actually have permissions to read the files in the directory.

If your files were larger I would avoid reading all into memory and/or storing the full content.

Comment: This does solve his problem incidentally, but it doesn't explain it--the fact that you use `join` with `glob` isn't going to tell a novice that he also needed it with listdir. It also solves another problem that he may be having but not know how to describe, and does explain that part, but I'm not sure he has that problem or not...

Comment: @abarnert, I added a bit more explanation, I think the OP is also definitely having the other problem.

Comment: You're right; now that I reread it, "'.idea' (??)" does seem to imply that either he needs `glob`, or he needs to skip hidden dot-files. Still, a better question than (??) embedded in the middle of the text might be easier to answer. :)

Comment: @abarnert, yep, I first thought it was idea  as in *do you have any idea?* until I deciphered the real meaning :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure you add the folder name to the file name, so you can find the file relative to where the script is executed.

To do so you want to use `os.path.join`, which as it's name suggests - joins paths. So, using [a generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
def find_get(folder):
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        relative_file_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
        with open(relative_file_path) as f:
            # read() gives the entire data from the file
            yield f.read()

# this consumes the generator to a list
files_data = list(find_get('filex'))
```

See what we got in the list that consumed the generator:

```
print files_data
```

---

It may be more convenient to produce tuples which can be used to construct a `dict`:

```
def find_get(folder):
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        relative_file_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
        with open(relative_file_path) as f:
            # read() gives the entire data from the file
            yield (relative_file_path, f.read(), )

# this consumes the generator to a list
files_data = dict(find_get('filex'))
```

You will now have a mapping from the file's name to it's content.

Also, take a look at the [answer by @Padraic Cunningham](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29978246/948550) . He brought up the `glob` module which is suitable in this case.

Comment: This doesn't solve his file not found error, because you're still using the filenames as if they were full pathnames. So, it'll produce the exact same result he already has.

Comment: still, it says IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.idea'

Comment: @abarnert thanks, I missed it or it was added later. Fixing answer :)

Comment: You're turning his iterable-of-lines file contents into big-string-of-bytes (which you could fix with `list(f)` in place of `f.read()`, if it's important to the OP—I have no idea whether it is…).

Comment: @abarnert I'm pretty sure that's what he meant There little login in all lines of all files where there is a loss of context. Even if it's not, it's easy to fix once he has an understanding of the code.

Comment: @ReutSharabani: I can't find that text anywhere but in your comment, or anything similar in his question. Did he explain his problem in a comment, and then delete that without putting the relevant information in the question? (If so, kudos on keeping track of what he wants…)

Comment: @abarnert actually my last comment got messed up (missing words, login -> logic ...) since I'm on mobile, but the point was I'm assuming that's what he wants, I don't know. There is little logic in losing the file context of the content by only printing the lines.

Comment: Oh. Well, anyway, as I said, if it isn't what he wants, as long as he knows what he wants, he can fix it trivially (e.g., `list(f)` instead of `f.read()`), and he hasn't told us what he wants, so nothing wrong with this guess.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're facing is simple: `listdir` returns *filenames*, not full pathnames. To turn them into pathnames you can access from your current working directory, you have to `join` them to the directory path:

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    pathname = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    with open(pathname) as f:
        # do stuff
```

So, in your case, there's a file named `.idea` in the `folder` directory, but you're trying to open a file named `.idea` in the current working directory, and there is no such file.

There are at least four other potential problems with your code that you also need to think about and possibly fix after this one:

- You don't handle errors. There are many very common reasons you may not be able to open and read a file--it may be a directory, you may not have read access, it may be exclusively locked, it may have been moved since your `listdir`, etc. And those aren't logic errors in your code or user errors in specifying the wrong directory, they're part of the normal flow of events, so your code should handle them, not just die. Which means you need a `try` statement.
- You don't do anything with the files but print out every line. Basically, this is like running `cat folder/*` from the shell. Is that what you want? If not, you have to figure out what you want and write the corresponding code.
- You open the same file twice in a row, without closing in between. At best this is wasteful, at worst it will mean your code doesn't run on any system where opens are exclusive by default. (Are there such systems? Unless you know the answer to that is "no", you should assume there are.)
- You don't close your files. Sure, the garbage collector will get to them eventually--and if you're using CPython and know how it works, you can even prove the maximum number of open file handles that your code can accumulate is fixed and pretty small. But why rely on that? Just use a with statement, or call close.

However, none of those problems are related to your current error. So, while you have to fix them *too*, don't expect fixing one of them to make the first problem go away.

Answer (score 0):

Full variant:

```py
import os

def find_get(path):
  files = {}
  for file in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,file)):
      with open(os.path.join(path,file), "r") as data:
        files[file] = data.read()
  return files

print(find_get("filex"))
```

Output:

```
{'1.txt': 'dsad', '2.txt': 'fsdfs'}
```

After the you could generate one file from that content, etc.

Key-thing:

- os.listdir return a list of files without full path, so you need to concatenate initial path with fount item to operate.
- there could be ideally used dicts :)
- os.listdir return files and folders, so you need to check if list item is really file

Comment: Any argument for -1 ?

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this; I think it was the first answer that actually explained and solved the problem at hand instead of just solving unrelated problems. But I wouldn't upvote it; it has the same problem with `isfile` as the other answers. Checking `isfile` is neither sufficient not necessary, and it introduces races. Just `try`.

Answer (score -1):

You should check if the file is actually file and not a folder, since you can't open folders for reading. Also, you can't just open a relative path `file`, since it is under a folder, so you should get the correct path with `os.path.join`. Check below:

```
import os
def find_get(folder):
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        if not os.path.isfile(file):
            continue  # skip other directories
        f = open(os.path.join(folder, file), 'r')
        for line in f:
            print line
```

Comment: You really don't want to use `isfile`; just `try` it and handle errors. The filesystem is one place where EAFP actually matters, rather than just being a stylistic choice, because it's the only way to avoid races.

Comment: Do you not know what a race is?

Comment: Besides, it doesn't really solve the problem you're trying to solve. There are plenty of reasons opening a file can fail besides being a directory. For example, you may not have read access. So you still need the try/except anyway.

Comment: Ok, I need the try/except, I never said I didn't. At least there is less overhead with excluding directories sooner. But I can agree with your point. P.S. When you are explaining something to a person, try not to patronize them. It doesn't serve your cause.

Comment: but anyway, EAFP is not a good practice. Try/Catch is needed, but shouldn't serve as check procedure.

Comment: @Reishin: Says who? EAFP is fundamental to Python's design (even a simple `for` statement relies on it). If you don't think it's a good practice, you're using the wrong language.

Comment: What makes you think there's less overhead excluding directories sooner? For readable files, you're doing two syscalls (and two Python function calls) instead of one. For unreadable files, you're doing two plus an exception instead of one plus an exception. For directories, you're doing one plus an exception instead of one. You're adding more syscalls and not removing any. Unless you think exceptions are orders of magnitude slower than function calls in Python (which they aren't), where do you think the reduced overhead would come from?

Comment: Meanwhile, if I explain what's wrong with `isfile` and you just ask "what is wrong with `isfile`", how exactly should I answer that? I have no idea which part of my explanation you didn't understand.

Comment: @abarnert all what u told makes a sense and i clearly understand that, but it's more easy to understand `isfile` that why was generated `PermissionError` when you try open a folder, instead of `IOError` one. And try to guess after, you don't have a permissions or it's just a folder? And summary you should handle at least 3 exceptions: `IOError`, `FileNotFoundError` and `PermissionError`. But all of this come of from OP question.

Comment: @Reishin: First, you don't get a `PermissionError` when you try to open a directory, you get an `IsADirectoryError`, which gives you exactly the information you say you need but don't have. If you need to handle `PermissionError`s and `IsADirectoryError`s differently, it's a lot clearer to do so in separate `except` blocks than with separate `isfile`, `acces`, etc. calls. And if you _don't_ need to handle them separately, just represent them to the user, you can trivially do so in a single `except IOError:` that just includes the exception repr in the logs, or whatever, which you can't do LBYL

Comment: @abarnert no, only on unix like systems, and only for python 3k you get `IsADirectoryError`. On python2.7 you will get `IOError` and on [Windows system](http://pastebin.com/dxBEG5yv) you will get `PermissionError`. So main behavior depends on platform and python version, which cause not use that in questions without os platform mentioned and python version. handle only top error IOError will helps, but then you probably don't carry about missed files or reason.

Comment: @Reishin: On Python 2, there are no separate `IOError` subclasses, so if that's the issue, then the whole "you have to handle `IOError` and `PermissionError`" thing is a red herring. At any rate, you have to know what exceptional cases you want to do something special with to actually do it. Knowing that, you can always do whatever you want to do with exceptions clearly and simply; that may or may not be clear with LBYL. Not to mention that with LBYL you don't have a fallback for cases you _didn't_ think of, and all the other problems mentioned above.

Comment: no, it's not a case, i give just an comparison table across os types and python  versions. At this point we gone far from OP simple question to design patterns discussion and i'd like to continue, (i like us dialog and possibly i can get something from this to myself) but we spam here a lot of comments in unrelated answer :)